# Optimizing an 2D-NIntegrate in terms of speed

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, nonlinear

I am trying to optimize the following function further in terms of speed while maintaining the given Precision and correctness.

The function decribes the two dimensional convolution of a sum of Bessel functions and a Gaussian along one axis.

```
    model[Q_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ, sigma_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ] :=
Log10[0.25*NIntegrate[Abs[Sum[(I*f)^(j - 1)*(1/(Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + z^2]))^(j)*BesselJ[j, 2*Q*Sqrt[(x - y)^2 + z^2]], {j, 1, 20}]]^2*A*Exp[-(x^2 + z^2)/((sigma)^2)],
 {x, -Infinity,Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> {"EvenOddSubdivision", "VerifyConvergence" -> False, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"}]]
```

I have tested out various Methods for the function and already a achieved a great improvement compared to using standard methods. However, I am curious if there are even more improvements possible.

This function is used to fit a certain set of data which can take up to several hours, example:

```
    nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[data1, {model[Q, f, sigma, A, y]}, {{Q, 1.76}, {f, 2.4}, {sigma, 0.2}, {A, 85000}}, y,
EvaluationMonitor :> Print["Q=", Q, ". f=", f, ". sigma=", sigma, ". A=", A]][  "ParameterTable"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide your data  for a minimal working example.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.